# Multi language in edittext android

Tags: android

I have a form login with Edittext. I want to post and get multi language (English, Japanese,..) but it don't work without English. Keyboard supports other languages.
Help me, thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to create the labels/text in different language. If yes, use the Android Localisation support.

eg. you can create a res/values-it to store italian version of ... values.

or drawable-ru-rRU to store russian pictures etc.

More info 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html